# Yii, PHPExcel throwing Fatal Errors

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

I have imported PHPExcel into /protected/extensions/phpexcel, followed all the steps. Created an action to call the createExcel action.

But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs...\protected\controllers\SiteController.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: Class 'CListIterator' not found in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\collections\CList.php on line 90

It was actually generating and working fine the day before. No changes were made to any file the next day. Suddenly this error shows up.

Can I know what may cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's the Autoload's problem. Just follow this link below:

[How to use PHPExcel external library with Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/101/how-to-use-phpexcel-external-library-with-yii/)

Just simply disable the autoload.